# fullcalendar.io use event limit but always show events with class x

Tags: jquery, html, css, events, fullcalendar

**What i want**
limit events but only for some event category
i have two categories Persons and Events, persons must be limited but not Events it must be always at box.

**Problem**
If i set `eventLimit` 1 it will show me just More link and hides that 1 event

This is my plugin
[fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

can u help me find any solution for my problem?

```
editable: false,
eventLimit: 1,
```

Comment: Before rendering the calendar, you need to count your 'Events' event then save it to a variable let's say `x` . Then use `eventLimit: x + n` where `n` is the limit of desired `Persons` event. Also, use `eventOrder` to show 'Events' first.

Comment: tnx for replay.
i mean limit for one day box.
if i have 3 events and 3 persons i want to put persons into "more" link and show 3 events normal in day box

Comment: yes that's what the comment above is describing already.

Comment: @ADyson I think he meant different `eventLimit` per day? Do you think it is possible? Coz I don't :P

Comment: @Cons7an7ine good point, I hadn't thought of that. It would only be possible by building some completely custom code I think.

Comment: i think. fullcalendar need to add this feature

Comment: @KAKHA13 In that case go to https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Requesting-Features/